# How can I buffer a pipe with minimal added latency?

Tags: shell, python3, pv

I am connecting to a debian system over a serial connection and streaming real time data from a pressure sensor. Originally I used:

```
python3.6 pressure_streamer.py
```

The data is being produced at 32.1kB/s and it needs to be buffered in case the reader is busy. I can add a buffer with the pv command:

```
python3.6 pressure_streamer.py | pv --quiet --buffer-size 10M
```

With pv the data appears bunched up into 8k writes in the steady state. This adds ~250ms of latency.

Is there a way to buffer which adds less latency?